# How to make merge using a few columns in one Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas Data Frames like below:

table1

```
ID
------
11
22
33
44
```

table2

```
ID1    ID2   ID3    VAL
----------------------
11  | 108  | 5    | 5555
45  | 22   | 1146 | 4567
67  | 4987 | 33   | 105
```

And I need to merge table1 and table2 using column "ID" from table1 and columns: "ID1", "ID2", "ID3" from table2.

I want to do like that:

1. merge on ID and ID1
2. if ID does not merge with ID1 --> merge ID and ID2
3. if ID does not merge with ID1 and ID2 --> merge ID and ID3
4. give NULL or NaN if rows does not merge

So as a result I need table like below:

```
ID    ID1    ID2    ID3    VAL
-------------------- -----------
11  | 11   | NULL | NULL | 5555
22  | NULL | 22   | NULL | 4567
33  | NULL | NULL | 33   | 105
44  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
```

How can i do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: are table1 and table2 of the same length ?  Same number of rows ?

Comment: No, table2 is shorter, table2 has smaller number of rows than table1, so it has to be table1 left join table2 so as to to sure that we will have all rows from table1 and merge to that fitted rows from table2 :)

Comment: EBDS I edited question, now it is more readable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for c in df2.columns[:-1]:
    df1[c] = np.where(df1['ID'].eq(df2[c]),df1['ID'],np.nan)
df1 = df1.join(df2.iloc[:,-1])
```

|  | ID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 11 | 11 | nan | nan | 5555 |
| 1 | 22 | nan | 22 | nan | 4567 |
| 2 | 33 | nan | nan | 33 | 105 |
| 3 | 44 | nan | nan | nan | nan |